# Javaでログイン時の「パスワードを記憶する」を作るには

Tags: java, html, seaser2

現在Java、Seasar2(SAStrats/S2JDBC)、JSP、PostgreSQLで
DBを使ったWebアプリケーションを作っています。

質問があるのですが、

**Javaでログイン時の「パスワードを記憶する」機能を作るにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？**

次のような機能です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

作り方やサンプルコードを調べているのですが、なかなか見つけられません。
もし情報を提供できる方がいれば、参考ページのURLなどを教えて頂けると助かります。

Comment: 各ブラウザに付いてるlogin情報の記録機能じゃダメなんですか？

Comment: 豚吐露さん
返信ありがとうございます。
今回は機能を実現したいというよりも
この機能を自分で作ってどのような仕組みなのか勉強したいという想いの方が強いんです。
なのでブラウザの記録機能ではなく、自分で作ってみたいと思っています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ブラウザの認証画面はBasic認証と呼ばれる方式で、ID・パスワードの入力と、1回ログインしたらそのときの認証情報を今後も使用するかどうを、ブラウザ側の機能として実現しています。

今回質問者さんがやりたいことは、この機能を使わずに、Java EEアプリケーションで独自に実装をしたい、ということだと思われます。

その場合はフォーム認証というやり方になります。ログイン画面は自分でHTMLなりJSP・JSFなりで作成し、認証処理、認証結果の保存を自力でやることになります。

方法としてはすでにご自身で回答のとおりCookieを使った方法が良いでしょう。注意点としては、Cookieに保存するのはIDやパスワードそのものではなく、それと紐づいた独自の生成値にすること、ドメイン属性を設定し自分のサイトだけにCookieを送信するようにすること、環境的に可能であればSSLを有効にし、CookieにもSecure属性を付けること、です。

Answer (score 1):

次のようなやり方で取り組んでみたいと思います。

cookieを使用。
１．最初のログイン時にログイン情報をDBなどに保存。その際ログイン状態を表すユニークなID(文字列など)をDBのキーとしておく
２．そのキーをCookieに保存(有効期限付きで)
３．サイトが開かれた際に、２のCookieがあればＤＢを検索
４．DBにログイン情報が存在すればログイン状態とする

参照
http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14107632694

大方やりたいことは合っているのでもう少し勉強してみます。